How connectedness of $O(n)$ or $SO(n)$ implies the connectedness of $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)$ or $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$
I was reading section 1.3.2 of Compact Lie group by Mark R. Sepanski.

Definitions: Let $\mathcal C^+_n(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathcal C^-(\mathbb R)$ be the subalgebras of $\mathcal C_n(\mathbb R)$ spanned by all products of an even number and an odd number of elements of $\mathbb R^n$ respectively. The automorphism $\alpha$ called the main involution of $\mathcal C_n(\mathbb R)$ act as multiplication by $\pm1$ on $\mathcal C_n^{\pm}(\mathbb R)$. Conjugation is an anti-involution on $\mathbb C_n(\mathbb R)$ defined by $(x_1x_2\cdots x_k)^*=(-1)^kx_k\cdots x_1$ for $x_i\in\mathbb R^n$. Let $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)=\{ 
g\in\mathcal C_n(\mathbb R):gg^*=1\text{ and }\alpha(g)xg^*\in\mathbb R^n\:\:\forall x\in\mathbb R^n \}$  Define the homomorphism $\mathcal A:\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ by $(\mathcal Ag)x=\alpha(g)x g^*.$

Lemma 1.38. $\mathcal A$ is a covering map of $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)$ onto $\operatorname{O}(n)$ with $\ker\mathcal A=\{\pm1\}$ $$\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)\stackrel{\mathcal A}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{O}(n)$$
I faced some confusion about the following answer:

$\mathcal{A}$ is a covering map: $\pi$ has constant rank with $N= \operatorname{rk}\:\pi=$ $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb{R})$ since ker $\pi=\{ \pm 1\}$. For any $g \in \operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb{R})$, the Rank Nullity Theorem says there exists cubical charts $(U, \varphi)$ of $g$ and,$(V,\psi)$ of $\pi(g)$ so that $\psi \circ \pi \circ \varphi^{-1}\left(x_1, \ldots, x_N\right)=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_N, 0, \ldots,0\right)$ with $\dim \operatorname{O}(n)-N$ zeros. Using the second countability of $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and the Baire category theorem, surjectivity of $\pi$ implies $\operatorname{dim} O(n)=N$. In particular, $\pi$ restricted to $U$ is a diffeomorphism onto $V$. Since $\operatorname{ker} \pi=\{ \pm 1\}, \pi$ is also a diffeomorphism of $-U$ onto $V$. Finally, injectivity of $\pi$ on $U$ implies that $(-U) \cap U=\emptyset$ so that the connected components of $\pi^{-1}(V)$ are $U$ and $-U$.

Question: How do we use the Baire category theorem here? Actually, I feel I do not completely understand the reasoning the author uses to show that $\mathcal A$ is a covering map here. And From here I have another doubt about how we connect Lie stuff in our Clifford algebra settings. Like did we really use the fundamental theorem of Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin to bring the Lie group notion here?

So, the quotient map from one Lie group to another with a discrete kernel is a covering map hence $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)/\{\pm1\}$ is a covering map as @MoisheKohan mentioned in the comment. I hope this resolves the first question.
If we restrict $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)$ group to $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)=\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)\cap\operatorname{Cl}_n^+(\mathbb R)$, then we have the covering map:
$$\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)\stackrel{\mathcal A}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{SO}(n)$$
Theorem 1.40. $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$ is the connected ($n\geq 2$) simply connected $(n\geq 3)$ two-fold cover of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$. The covering homomorphism is given by $\mathcal A$ with $\ker\mathcal A=\{\pm1\}$ with an exact sequence: $$\{1\}\rightarrow\{\pm1\}\rightarrow \operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)\stackrel{\mathcal A}{\rightarrow}\operatorname{SO}(n)\rightarrow\{I\}$$
From here we get:

If $M$ is a connected manifold then the covering space of M is classified by subgroups of the fundamental group of M. Furthermore, the degree of a covering map $M_H\rightarrow M$ corresponding to a subgroup $H\leq \pi_1(M)$ equal to the index of $H$ in $\pi_1(M)$.

I never formally taught algebraic topology but I have some basic knowledge. Where can I find the proof of this theorem? I guess by Invoking this theorem we can say the degree of $\mathcal A$ is $2$.
Question: We knew that $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is connected and $\operatorname{O}(n)$ is not. Now, how can we use this information to prove the theorem 1.40.?

From here I got another doubt about how we connect Lie stuff in our Clifford algebra settings. Like did we really use fundamental theorem of Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin to bring Lie group notion here?

Every topological subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is 2nd countable; aĺl manifolds are 2nd countable by definition. Do you know the definition of 2nd countability?

I understand it after realizing the isomorphism $\operatorname{Cl}_n(\mathbb R)\cong\mathbb R^{2^n}$ @MoisheKohan I will remove that part from my question. But still don't understand the rest. And t\hanks for your response.

You do not need any of these results. All what you need is a general lemma that the quotient map from one Lie group to another with discrete kernel is a covering map. This is completely elementary and  was asked and answered several times on MSE, for instance, I have done it recently here.

Wow, that's mean here $\operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb R)/{\pm1}$ is a covering map invoking this theorem. Though I am not completely understand the last part of your answer. I comment their with my doubt. Thank you very much for enlightening me with such beautiful result @MoisheKohan

Consider the homomorphism $\tilde{\det}=\det\circ\pi:\text{Pin}_n(\Bbb R)\to{\pm1}$.


When $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is any discrete subgroup of $G$,
then the projection $\pi: G \rightarrow H\backslash G$ (the space of left cosets, with the quotient topology) is a covering projection.

And we know that,
$$
\pi: \operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to O(n) \cong \{\pm 1\} \backslash \operatorname{Pin}_n(\mathbb{R})
$$
Hence, it's a covering map.

Proposition 1.32. (Hatcher) The map $p_*:\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)\rightarrow(X,x_0)$ induced by a covering space. The number of sheets of the covering space equals the index of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

We can use this proposition to say $\mathcal A$ is a double cover for $SO(n)$ if we know that $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$ is the universal cover of $SO(n)$. Because then $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ will be trivial and we already knew that $\pi_1(SO(n))=\mathbb Z_2,n\geq3$. But I don't know how to show the $\operatorname{Spin}_n(\mathbb R)$ is the universal cover of $SO(n)$.
